# Why would database snapshot loops run far too many loops when app is built new vs when just restarted or logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

What I observe: After an app has been built on iOS; if I log in an out the correct number of loops run. However, if I build the app new with the user still signed in (then it goes automatically to the homepage), way too many snapshot loops get run.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
let refArtists2 = Database.database().reference().child("people").queryOrdered(byChild: "caption").queryStarting(atValue:myInt).queryEnding(atValue: myInt1)
var handle: UInt = 0
handle = refArtists2.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {  snapshot in
    ....
  self.query1 = geoFire.query(at: self.dict, withRadius: 500)
  self.handle1 = self.query1?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
  })
  self.handle2 = self.query1?.observe(.keyExited, with: { key1, location in
  })
  self.query1?.observeReady({
    while let people = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
        if people.key != thisUsersUid && self.componentArray.contains(people.key) {
            print(self.componentArray,"man")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                if snapshot.exists() && self.people.isEmpty == false {
                    self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
                    self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: self.handle1)
                    self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: self.handle2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The key print to look at is "man". If there are 3 users that get displayed, man is printed 3 times, so loop is done 3 times. However, in the instance where way too many loops are run, it seems man is printed for each iteration of users that are within 500 miles.

Comment: The question is a bit vague *correct number* and *way too many* doesn't really tell us what you're expecting. Additionally, once a user is authenticated, Firebase remembers that user, so the next time the app is run, they stay logged in. So it's not clear why that code is running if the user is logged out. Can you clarify and update the question?

Comment: @Jay my bad, I forgot to add the part of print("man") that explains what `way too many` looks like. I have now added that. The code is not running if the user is logged out. What I meant is: if I have the app running and I log out of user A, log into user B, the issue does not occur. However, if user A or B is logged and I close the app and build it again via Xcode (goes directly to homepage/user is still logged in), this problem sometimes occurs.

Comment: The question is still pretty vague and I am not following the code. You're setting up a .keyEntered observer here `self.handle1 = self.query1?.observe` but not doing anything with those keys within the closure. Then, you're running a query `.observeReady` with a radius of 500 but that will return everything within that radius. And that's totally unrelated to the .keyEntered and .keyExited data so. what's the correlation? Within the .observeReady block you're implementing a DispatchQueue which is usually not needed to remove an observer. Essentially - what you're attempting to do is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ended up being related to the `while let` loop. Using `for in` has fixed it.